# Need better logic for data initiation using nextjs, featherjs, and feather-reactive

Tags: javascript, observable, server-side-rendering, feathersjs, next.js

I am trying out featherjs and nextjs. Right now somehow i can get initial data from server using nextjs SSR, and subscribing to my api using feathersjs.

I don't really now why it works and what really happen here. Maybe someone has better implementation about this ? Or did i using these library in a wrong way ?

The idea is for component to render the initial props that get rendered by server on first load, and then for next request use observable to fetch the state.

This my code for books page. It just showing list of books :

```
import React from 'react';

import Main from '../layouts/Main';
import client from '../scripts/feathers-client';

const clientService = client.service('api/books');

export default class Books extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    if (this.props && this.props.books) {
      this.state = {books: this.props.books};
    } else {
      this.obs = clientService.watch().find().subscribe(books => {
        this.setState({books: books});
      });
    }
  }

  static async getInitialProps ({ req }) {
    if (req) {
      let service = req.app ? req.app.service('api/books') : {};
      return { books: await service.find() };
    } else {
      return { books: ''};
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    if (this.obs) {
      this.obs.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  render () {
    const renderBooks = this.state ?
      <ol>
        {this.state.books.data.map(book => (
          <li key={book._id}>{book.author}, {book.title}, liked: {book.liked}<p>{book.synopsis}</p></li>
        ))}
      </ol>
      :
      '';
    return (
      <Main>
        <p>List of books :</p>
        {renderBooks}
      </Main>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hmm, mainly i am asking a better architecture on using nextjs and featherjs, as my code above i am using feathers-reactive with rxjs to watch data. And i am planning to use redux. Maybe someone has a tips on this ?

Comment: Such a question is not suitable for stack overflow.

Comment: well, i am kinda just throwing it out, in hope i got some direction on this.